# check copies of ReadLock in java

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a method which checks if such transaction holds a lock on one specific thing. But for ReadLock, there can be multiple ReadLocks on the same object. Is there a way I can check how many copies I have for that object?

Comment: Sorry about typo, the question is how to check the copies of ReadLock

Comment: are you talking about aquiring lock on object ?

Comment: yes, I am implementing a simple database system which requires write and read lock

Comment: What do you mean by copies of the object ?

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you need to know how many ReadLocks are held? If you want to limit the concurrency to a maximum of N you could use a Semaphore with N permits - but note that this does not distinguish between read/write. If you just want to know for debugging purposes, you could implement something yourself using a counter incremented inside the readlock and decremented immediately prior to release.

Comment: The whole idea of a read lock is that there can be as many as you like, but no concurrent write locks. There is something seriously wrong with a system that needs to know how many read locks there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [ReentrantReadWriteLock.getReadLockCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html#getReadLockCount%28%29)?